# How to list the realisations of an impure derivation?

Tags: nix

I'm using Nix 2.15.1. I have this impure derivation:

```
$ cat foo.nix
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
 in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "impure";
  __impure = true; # marks this derivation as impure
  buildCommand = "date > $out";
}
```

Because of its impurity, each time it's realised, it results in a new store path:

```
$ nix build --json -f foo.nix
[{"drvPath":"/nix/store/32pdpzaj793kg4q1paxc6bhzhnf93n8j-impure.drv","outputs":{"out":"/nix/store/pkiv6mw6cbivnj9cam44gb94q9lm6asq-impure"},"startTime":0,"stopTime":0}]
$ nix build --json -f foo.nix
[{"drvPath":"/nix/store/32pdpzaj793kg4q1paxc6bhzhnf93n8j-impure.drv","outputs":{"out":"/nix/store/h0q8z5lm0s1w6902kg16d1zfjdc5qhlx-impure"},"startTime":0,"stopTime":0}]
```

Now suppose I knew about `foo.nix` but not about any previous realisations, and I wanted to list the realisations, if they exist. I've tried

```
$ nix realisation info --json -f foo.nix
```

But it results in the error

```
error: cannot operate on an output of the unbuilt derivation 'sha256:ddffc26775f61118da8597d1f2f62c544ec92461b31b5b1075ed8689a7ee8292!out'
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or is it simply impossible to know which realisations a given impure derivation has in the store?

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but it gets the job done:

```
ls -d /nix/store/*impure*
```

(Replace `impure` with whatever the actual name of your derivation is.)